# Whilst trying to use the VScode debugger, it opens for 2 seconds, closes, and I don't receive an error message

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a python file that I have in my VScode and whenever I press the play button for "Python: Current" I get a message in the terminal like this and I don't receive an error message. I am using macOS

brianw@BLT-3 VScode %  cd "/Users/brianw/Desktop/Coding Projects/VScode" ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/brianw/wpilib/2022/vscode/code-portable-data/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 51951 -- "/Users/brianw/Desktop/Coding Projects/VScode/Python-Code-Challanges/debugg.py"

I have looked almost everywhere on the internet and couldn't find a solution for over an hour. I tried to ask the chatGDP bot and it was no help, I did everything it said to troubleshoot, but nothing worked. I tried looking it up, but I got a troubleshooting problem that I couldn't fix, "Make sure that you have the correct Python interpreter selected in the VSCode settings. You can do this by going to the bottom left corner of the VSCode window, clicking on the Python icon, and selecting the interpreter you want to use." and then "In the search bar at the top of the Settings window, type "python.pythonPath" and press enter." but I searched it and nothing popped up.

Edit: The problem was the data and the breakpoint were in an uncalled function.

Comment: what does the program do? Does it happen with the smallest Python script that prints a few text lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to debug python code in vscode:

1. Go to the run and debug option in the side bar.
2. Click your current python file for debugging.

But the important step is to place a **breakpoint** in your program before starting to debug your code..

If you didn't place any **breakpoints** it will close automatically.

Comment: I have a breakpoint yet I'm still getting this error, it was mentioned before to add a             "pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"], to my launch.json file because without it, it gives the output
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

Comment: ```Executing N:\debugpy-issue\mre.py
0.02s - Debugger warning: The os.path.realpath.__code__.co_filename (ntpath.py)
0.00s - is not absolute, which may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Waiting for a debug client to attach...``` Is this your error?

Comment: the error I provided in my other comment was the exact one which happened. This has the general gist of mine though, it has PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 too. I did not do anything about PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 as I didn't know what to do. Which may be my problem, 
My launch.json  is:

Comment: {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Brian why don't you edit your question with this type of info